# cocos2d-x CCTouchDispatcher - no sharedDispatcher

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm currently porting an ObjC cocos2d game to cocos2d-x, but I'm encountering some problems when trying to create a registerWithTouchDispatcher method, at the moment I'm doing

```
void GameLayer::registerWithTouchDispatcher()
{
    CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this,0,true);
}
```

but this gives an error 'No member named sharedDispatcher' in cocos2d::CCTouchDispatcher'.

Is there another way that this must be done in cocos2d-x?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using 2.0, they have been merged in to CCDirector. 
please use

```
            CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()
```

Comment: CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true); - add the rest of it

Answer (score 1):

use those code instead ccdirector. put the code to cclayer init function.

```
setTouchMode(kCCTouchesOneByOne);

registerWithTouchDispatcher();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the cocos2d-x you can do like this.

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this,0);
```