# Determine if object is touched/tapped

Tags: ios, touch, cocos2d-x

I've just started using Cocos 2D-X in Xcode.

I'm trying to make a balloon popping game in order to learn the Cocos 2D-X library. So far, I'm able to show sprites and make them move. As for touch, I'm able to get the touch coordinates (and print it out on the console).

Now, what I want to do is to have the balloons (a `CCSprite` object) "pop" (be removed from the layer). I'm looking around for solutions and one of them is to check if the touch location is in the `CCSprite` rect. But all the things that I found are either outdated or written in Objective C.

How do I determine if the touch location is within the rect of the balloon? Are there other ways aside from this method?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**:
I did it by putting the balloons in an array and checking if the touch location hits one of the balloons in that array. Now, I'm trying to make a Balloon class and handle it from there. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lucky enough because I have a game that use balloons,
Below is my code, you can finish the Balloon Class and you can use it the same as CCSprite

Example:

```
Balloon* blueBalloon = Balloon::spriteWithFile("balloon_blue.png");
this->addChild(blueBalloon);
```

h file:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
using namespace cocos2d;

class Balloon : public cocos2d::CCSprite, public CCTargetedTouchDelegate {
public:
virtual void onEnter();
virtual void onExit();
virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
};
```

cpp file:

```
void Balloon::onEnter(){
    CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);
    CCSprite::onEnter();
}
void Balloon::onExit(){
    CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);
    CCSprite::onExit();
}

void Balloon::ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event){
    //do what you want
}
void Balloon::ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event){
    //do your job here
}

bool Balloon::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event){
    CCPoint touchLocation = this->getParent()->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch);
    if (CCRect::CCRectContainsPoint(this->boundingBox(), touchLocation)) {
        this->playBalloonSound();
        this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
    }

    return true;
}
```

or you can refer to my code in this post [cocos2d subclassing sprite to handle touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354689/cocos2d-subclassing-sprite-to-handle-touch)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't planning on applying OOP (creating custom classes) in cocos2d-x (still editing that HelloWorld sample) yet but it seems to solve a lot of problems. I have a question though, on `ccTouchBegan`, the `removeFromParentAndCleanup( bool )` one, is that a method of `CCSprite` (meaning I don't write that method myself)?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually, it is a method of CCNode.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I assume `Balloon::onEnter( )` and `Balloon::onExit( )` are called when the `Balloon` object is created/destroyed, am I right?

Comment: Weird. I made a balloon class like that one above but I get errors on the line `CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);`. It said `sharedDispatcher( ) is not a member of CCTouchDispatcher` or something like that. I fixed it by replacing it with `CCDirector::sharedDirector() -> getTouchDispatcher() -> addTargetedDelegate( this, 0, true );`. Why the error though?

Comment: I think you are using version 2.0, in this case, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264191/cocos2d-x-cctouchdispatcher-no-shareddispatcher

Comment: Yes, the OnEnter() are called just after the object is created and before it is rendered on screen, and onExit() is called after the object is removed from parent and before it is destroyed.

Comment: When I do `Balloon* blueBalloon = Balloon::create("balloon_blue.png");` I get `Cannot initialize a variable of type 'Balloon *' with an rvalue of type 'cocos2d::CCSprite *'`. What has changed?

Comment: because the create function returns a CCSprite. you need to write your own `create(const char* filename)` in the Balloon Class.

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d-x 3.0 you can try this:

```
auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

listener->setSwallowTouches(true);

listener->onTouchBegan = [&](Touch* touch, Event* event){

    if (this->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(this->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

};

Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```