# Create a sprite from a class that inherits CCSprite

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I have a `Balloon` class (see *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755431/determine-if-object-is-touched-tapped)*) that inherits from `CCSprite`. I have given it properties like `balloonSpeed` and `balloonStrength`. I seem to be having problems in it, though.

What I want to do is that when I make an instance of the `Balloon` class, I want it to do the following:

- Give it a texture (a PNG file of a balloon).
- Set properties like `balloonSpeed` and `balloonStrength`.
- Add actions to make it move and accept touch input.

When the object is touched, I want to:

- Count if # of taps = `balloonStrength`. if so, destroy Balloon.

I have done a simpler version of this where a `Balloon` object is destroyed when it is touched. I want to apply OOP and custom classes here but I can't seem to get the right way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then the h file should looks like below:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
using namespace cocos2d;

class Balloon : public cocos2d::CCSprite, public CCTargetedTouchDelegate {
public:
float balloonSpeed;
int balloonStrength;
int numberOfTaps;
virtual void onEnter();
virtual void onExit();
virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
};
```

and in your touch method:

```
bool Balloon::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event){
    CCPoint touchLocation = this->getParent()->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch);
    if (CCRect::CCRectContainsPoint(this->boundingBox(), touchLocation)) {
        this->numberOfTaps++;
        if(this->balloonStrength == this->numberOfTaps){ 
            this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

you can use it after you add the blueBalloon as a child of a layer or node as below:

```
blueBalloon->balloonSpeed = 2.0f;
blueBalloon->numberOfTaps = 0;
blueBalloon->balloonStrength = 5;
```

Comment: Yes, I got the part where I am able to set properties like balloonSpeed and the others. But I had problem actually creating the object/sprite. Do I use `Balloon myBalloon = Balloon::create( );` or `CCSprite * myBalloon = Balloon::create( );`?

Comment: I think it is Balloon* myBalloon = Balloon::create( );